# Getting the respsonse: "INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project id 'X' , is malformed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs, dotenv

I'm trying to connect to google firestore and for some reason my `process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID` keeps spitting out the error:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.17.1): Connection GRPC stream error. Code: 3 Message: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project id 'name-of-project', is malformed: it either contains invalid characters or is too long. Look at https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects for instructions in how to get a project's id.

> [2020-08-04T23:53:51.550Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.17.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project id 'name-of-project', is malformed: it either contains invalid characters or is too long. Look at https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects for instructions in how to get a project's id.

When I paste the project ID directly in, it works and connects. But when I try to use the process.env solution for whatever reason it doesnt accept it despite the fact that it's literally returning the correct project id that I am otherwise pasting in directly in the successful runs.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/analytics';
require('dotenv').config();

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};
// Initialize Firebase
try {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
} catch (err) {
  // we skip the "already exists" message which is
  // not an actual error when we're hot-reloading
  if (!/already exists/.test(err.message)) {
    console.error('Firebase initialization error', err.stack);
  }
}

// const firebaseAnalytics = firebase.analytics();
const firebaseStorage = firebase.storage();
const firebaseFirestore = firebase.firestore();

export { firebaseStorage, firebaseFirestore };
```

I don't know why it's doing this. I've never had this issue before. Any thoughts?

Comment: The error is complaining about the value you provided for `projectId`, which we can't see here.  Without knowing the specific value, we can't say what's wrong it it.

Comment: @DougStevenson hello it's located in my `.env.local` file with the value of: `FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID='parakeat-a1-7706'`.  Taking the `' '` off didn't solve anything either. I was hoping that would have made a difference.

Comment: Are you running this in any serverless environment like Firebase function or something?

Comment: @vitooh nope i am not

Comment: You shouldn't need to add `require('dotenv').config()`. Do you have an `.env.local` file in your project?